# IE will not load my site

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

My website is at http://www.swell-sites.com.  I can not get it to load on IE (6,7,8...it seems OK on 9 and up).  I built the site with bootstrap, plus added in a responsive menu from Code Canyon and am using WowSlider for the slideshow as well.

I have tried peeling away various JS scripts but to no avail...  The coding is actually pretty simple, I'm a bit stumped.

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

....a few minutes later.  OK.  It seems to be loading now, but the css isn't working out the way I want it to.  Specifically, I have a menu substitute that's only supposed to show up at 750px or smaller that is showing up and there's some general weirdness to the menus and so on.  But the main issue of just showing up is solved.

Comment: Try removing the Conditional Comments-voodoo that is going on to insert different `html` elements first …

Comment: Thank you very much.  That seems to at least get it showing up.  It's not showing exactly what I want to see, but it's a huge step in the right direction.   Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't doing what you expect?

Comment: Certainly. Code for my logo: 

<a href="index.html"><img src="../images/logo.png" alt="Swell Sites Lawyer Website Marketing" class="logo"></a>

Here is the CSS for the rule "logo": 

.logo {
 width: 80%;
 max-width: 352px;
 max-height: 122px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 734px){
.logo {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 352px;
 max-height: 122px;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
}

----I'll put together some more examples, but is there a larger reason why,    A. (using Broswerstack) My website looks like the screen is under 770px, when it's not?  and B. That ie seems to be ignoring my css in general???